# how to put a link into left side in gmail using gmail contextual gadget

Tags: gmail-contextual-gadgets

manifest.xml : demo.avinashi.com/DemoGapps/manifest.xml

gadget.xml : demo.avinashi.com/DemoGapps/gadget.xml

Here is my manifest file...I just wanted to build the gadget just like the streak hiring extension at www.streak.com..I have build the code till some level..but the problem is that I want the link of a gadget to the left side pan in gmail just like the other labels like inbox,sent items etc not at the google's universal navigation links that I already got..moreover, The GUI, that should be displayed based on the extractor in mail body such as "Resume", of a gadget is not displayed..Any help would be appreciated..Thank you in advance..